# VBA Code to shift sourcedata in an excel chart

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I am trying to update my sourcedata in a chart. I Don't want a dynamic range because the chart will pull each time from the new range with each button click. If I use a dynamic or named range, I am locked into that range.

I have tried:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate

ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select

ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("A1:C3").Offset(0,3)
```

This only works once, though. To be clear, I have a button to update a chart on a spreadsheet. When the button is clicked, the macro will look at the current data in the active chart and shift the source over 3 columns. This will happen each time the button is clicked and the data must stay on the sheet. I've exhausted everything I know and can find online the Goracle search.

Any help?

Thanks in advance,
Lilith

Answer (score 1):

The `SeriesCollection(j)` of the `ActiveChart` has always a `Formula` property that looks like this:

```
=SERIES(,,Sheet1!$A$1:$C$3,1)
```

So, you can add a custom function to your project that parses the string `Split` by `$` and returns the corresponding range shift of 3 columns:

```
Function ShiftBy3(ByVal formulaString As String) As String
    cRange = Split(formulaString, "$")(1) + Split(formulaString, "$")(2) + Split(formulaString, "$")(3) + Split(Split(formulaString, "$")(4), ",")(0)
    newAddress = Range(cRange).Offset(0,3).Address
    ShiftBy3 = Split(formulaString, "$")(0) + newAddress + "," + Split(Split(formulaString, "$")(4), ",")(1) 
End Function
```

and then shifting by just resetting the formula each time:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula = ShiftBy3(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula)
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to update the `Formula` property for each series on the chart:

```
Sub Tester()
Const SER As String = "=SERIES("
Dim s As Series, f As String, arr, rng1, rng2, sn
Dim cht As Chart

    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart
    sn = ActiveSheet.Name
    For Each s In cht.SeriesCollection
        f = s.Formula
        Debug.Print f '<<<added
        f = Replace(f, SER, "")
        f = Left(f, Len(f) - 1)
        arr = Split(f, ",")
        Set rng1 = Range(arr(1))
        Set rng2 = Range(arr(2))

        s.Formula = SER & Join(Array(arr(0), _
                rng1.Parent.Name & "!" & rng1.Offset(0, 3).Address(), _
                rng2.Parent.Name & "!" & rng2.Offset(0, 3).Address(), _
                arr(3)), ",") & ")"

    Next s

End Sub
```

Comment: You both are awesome. I tried Tim's code but it failed ("Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed") in line Set rng1=Range(arr(1)). I have tried Matteo's code because I'm not sure where to put it.  I am probably doing this wrong, too.

Comment: If you add `Debug.Print f` as shown above what output do you get ? (it will show up in the Immediate window - press Ctrl+G in the editor to open that)  Also - make sure you don't have `Option Base 1` at the top of your code module.

Comment: Nothing happened with the addition of the debug code, just the pop up debug still gives the same 1004 error on the same line, Set rng1=Range(arr(1))

Comment: Also using Ootion Explicit, not Option Base 1

Comment: That should be Option. My boss came up with some that is working, mostly. See answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code my boss came up with.

```
Dim var

var = Cells(4, 4)

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(Cells(1, 1 + var), Cells(3, 3 + var))
Cells(4, 4).Value = Cells(4, 4).Value + 3
```

Thank Tim and Matteo for all of you time and help. I really do appreciate it!